# How can I write questions and store the answers in the df to validate the company name matches in python?

Tags: python, matching

I am going through the process of matching company names from one unclean dataset (df_third) to clean dataset (df_gold). I have the closest match based in the df_third for a long list of companies over 200k i.e.

```
df_third
Name_Raw         Group1   
 Aecom Tech      AECOM
 Aecom-Amentum   AECOM       
 Aecom Govern    Govern
```

I'd like to ask the user "Confirm if ['Name_Raw'] should be grouped to ['Group1'] Y/N?

If they enter "Y" Mark to New [Validate] Column

If they enter "N" Mark to New [Validate] Column

and then ask for the next row.

I thought about using the Name_Raw as an index (since they'll be unique) but having trouble finding a way to loop the question and capture the answer.

Also, welcome any better ideas of handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get the results you want:

```
import pandas as pd

dd = { 
'Name_Raw': ['Aecom Tech','Aecom-Amentum','Aecom Govern'],
'Group1':['AECOM','AECOM','Govern']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
df['Validate'] = ""


for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    YN = "-"
    while ((YN and YN.upper() in "YN") == False): 
       YN = input (f"Confirm if ['{row['Name_Raw']}'] should be grouped to ['{row['Group1']}'] Y/N ")
    row['Validate'] = YN.upper()
    
print("\n", df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
Confirm if ['Aecom Tech'] should be grouped to ['AECOM'] Y/N Y
Confirm if ['Aecom-Amentum'] should be grouped to ['AECOM'] Y/N N
Confirm if ['Aecom Govern'] should be grouped to ['Govern'] Y/N Y

       Name_Raw  Group1 Validate
    Aecom Tech   AECOM        Y
 Aecom-Amentum   AECOM        N
  Aecom Govern  Govern        Y
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike67 works perfectly. do you have any recommendation for quick and easy user input validation. was looking at import pyinputplus - inputYesNo(). but hadn't gotten as far as implementing it.